# <li> element alignment - reduce space on left side of bullet

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I am having problem in aligning the `<li>` element on the left side.

In the image given below, you can see that there is space on the left side of every bullet. I want to delete that space so that both `Imported` & `100% Genuine` bullets are directly below green tick mark.

[image]

Here's the code I am using.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><ul style="margin:0;"><li>Imported</li></ul></td>
        <td><ul style="margin:0;"><li>Authentic & Licensed</li></ul></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><ul style="margin:0;"><li>100% Genuine</li></ul></td>
        <td><ul style="margin:0;"><li>200 GSM Paper Depth</li></ul></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `padding-left` attribute of the `ul`.

```
ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/upehik/1/

Although I have to wonder why you're using lists if you only have one item per list?

Comment: Some browsers may also have a default `margin-left` set for lists, so I recommend modifying both.

Comment: Thanks @Sachleen. I am having 4 items. I need to display 2 items in each row. So used table and 4 `ul`. Any better way to do it?

Comment: Jonah, I mentioned `margin:0` -- is it not sufficient? Should I mention like `margin:0; margin-left:0px` ??

Comment: @iSumitG you already have margin 0 so don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Oops ... I didn't see the `margin: 0` down in your HTML. Disregard my previous comment...

Answer (score 3):

Another option... Most web browsers by default have the bullets displayed outside of the content flow. You can change this by changing the `list-style-position` to `inside`. If you notice in the examples below, the bullets are shown in JSFiddle when they are inside, but not outside. The only other way to get the bullets to show when they are outside, is to set the `padding-left` for the `ul` element (which is in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfwen06p/)).

[Example with bullets inside](http://jsfiddle.net/tLkqnkkj/)

[Example with bullets outside](http://jsfiddle.net/jaym19td/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to change the padding-left of the `li` attribute.

```
li {
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `0` will make the text line up against the left side, pushing the bullet too far off the left. And it needs to be on the `ul` not the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it differently;

http://jsfiddle.net/EeHYg/

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers display lists in different ways.

The most consistent way of doing this is to set a padding and margin to 0 for the ul and its contained li elements.

After this, you may want to increase the ul margin to the desired level.